# Convert forms.RegexField to lower character in Django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-forms

I have a Form that has a field 'username'. This field is a rejexfield. Following is the code:

```
username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@a-z0-9+-]+$',
                            max_length=30,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),
                            label=_("Username"),
                            error_messages={'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
```

I want that this field should be saved in lower character.

For example, If i enter username as **aBCd123** , then it should be save as **abcd123**

I have tried 'form.username.lower()' to convert to lower characters but error occurs. Apparantly .lower() works for charfields.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said where you tried to call `lower()`. You should do it in the `clean_username` method of your form:

```
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    if username:
        return username.lower()
```